# in Word 2007 when I cut and paste a hyperlink from a website into the Word document it isn't making it a hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, hyperlink

I have Word 2007. I often cut and paste links from websites into Word documents. It isn't making them hyperlinks. They're just text and don't link.

Comment: but you can make it as a hyperlink after you copied a text.

Comment: Ok, and that is a problem? I don't see an actual question in your post.

Comment: I don't think Word makes what is detected as a link into a hyperlink until you press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel to do a little help:

For example, there is text, https://superuser.com. In Excel, key in formula

```
=HYPERLINK("https://superuser.com")
```

and it produces the text in hyperlink format.

Copy and paste it/them into Word.